# Firefox and Chrome inconsistently crashing all the time - seems related to gstreamer

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, crash, gstreamer

I'um using RHEL 6.7. My Firefox suddenly started crashing over and over again at the most random times possible. **The only real consistent crash I noticed is when I enable desktop notifications on Slack**.

The console shows this when Firefox crashes:

```
###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file /builds/slave/rel-m-rel-l64_bld-000000000000/build/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 1584
```

I looked for the error message online and many people reported that `gstreamer` is the problem. I tried reinstalling some of my gstreamer plug-ins, but with no success.

I then switched to Chrome and the same thing started happening... :( I keep getting the "Aw, snap" page. This is really impacting my work.

I have several colleagues with my same laptop, same browser version, same OS, same kernel... everything! They don't get the same issue.

I'm assuming other people have been through the same and possibly I haven't fixed gstreamer properly. Any thoughts?

```
[phil@oc0364286225 ~]$ sudo yum list installed|grep gstream
[sudo] password for phil: 
gstreamer.i686                  0.10.29-1.el6        @RHEL-67-x86_64            
gstreamer.x86_64                0.10.29-1.el6        @RHEL-67-x86_64            
gstreamer-devel.x86_64          0.10.29-1.el6        @RHEL-67-x86_64            
gstreamer-plugins-base.i686     0.10.29-2.el6        @RHEL-67-x86_64            
gstreamer-plugins-base.x86_64   0.10.29-2.el6        @RHEL-67-x86_64            
gstreamer-plugins-base-devel.x86_64
gstreamer-plugins-good.x86_64   0.10.23-3.el6        @RHEL-67-x86_64            
gstreamer-plugins-good-devel.x86_64
gstreamer-python.x86_64         0.10.16-1.1.el6      @RHEL-67-x86_64            
gstreamer-tools.x86_64          0.10.29-1.el6        @RHEL-67-x86_64            
phonon-backend-gstreamer.i686   1:4.6.2-28.el6_5     @RHEL-67-x86_64            
phonon-backend-gstreamer.x86_64 1:4.6.2-28.el6_5     @RHEL-67-x86_64
```

Comment: Can you add some links to sites that suggest that gstreamer is the issue? Chrome is not using gstreamer, so I don't see how it would be affected. Also I don't see how notifications would relate to gstreamer. Maybe you can run your browser from gdb to get a backtrace. And bt.w this is not a programming question, thus please ask on e.g. superuser.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ensonic. I also ran memtest86+ against my machine and found out many RAM errors. Unfortunately, even after replacing my RAM I keep getting the crashes... If it's not gstreamer (since Chrome doesn't use it, according to you) and it's not the RAM memory, any idea what else it could be?

Comment: BTW, the reason why I thought it was gstreamer is because most posts with failures at `ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp` mention gstreamer as being the cause of failure.

Comment: You should really add some links.```ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp``` just hints it is related to a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After replacing my RAM memory Chrome stopped crashing.

I am not sure what was wrong with Firefox, but it didn't seem to be the plug-ins. It is a tailored version created by my company. After a new version was released I stopped hitting the problem.